# How to check particular key value length in array of javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, react-native

I am getting response like below.

```
[
  {
    id: '508',
    class: 'class1',
    value: '0',
    profit: '2,
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '509',
    class: 'class2',
    value: '0',
    profit: '0',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '510',
    class: 'class3',
    value: '0',
    profit: '0',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '511',
    class: 'class',
    value: '0',
    profit: '2.40',
    color: 'black'
  }
]
```

I have to check if `profit` key length is more than 2 indexes some condition else other condition. 
Note: If profit has 0 value, then it will consider as empty only.

For that, I have done like below.

```
const profitArrayLength = sortedProfitData.keys('profit').length;
console.log('profitArrayLength is', profitArrayLength);
```

But, It is showing as undefined in console.

Comment: What do you mean by "key length"?

Comment: what do you mean with length? the string length? what should happen after the check? what have you tried? please highlight *"I have to check if profit key length is more than 2 indexes some condition else other condition."*!

Comment: Do you mean to check if `profit` is in double digits (`profit >= 10`)?

Comment: I just want to check if the profit key has the real values except 0. And that key values length more than 1 or not. thats it.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have tried const profitArrayLength = sortedProfitData.keys('profit').length;
which is showing undefined

Comment: please add the wanted result and the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, within filter callback check property is defined and check value.

```js
let data = [
  {
    id: '508',
    class: 'class1',
    value: '0',
    profit: '2',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '509',
    class: 'class2',
    value: '0',
    profit: '0',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '510',
    class: 'class3',
    value: '0',
    profit: '0',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '511',
    class: 'class',
    value: '0',
    profit: '2.40',
    color: 'black'
  }
];

let key  = 'profit';

let len = data.filter(o=> key in o && o[key] != 0 ).length

console.log(len);

console.log('Length is greater than 1   : ',  len > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds as if you want to see the number of objects that have a positive profit. To do that, you would want to use a filter operation. Filter operates on an array, checking each element against a condition, and then returning a new array out of the elements that satisfy that condition. Afterwards, you can check the length of that array to see how many elements satisfied that condition. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Here's an example usage, that you should try to understand to apply to your case of checking how many items have a positive profit. In this case, we have objects with values a, b, and c. In my fake example here, I'm going to filter out every item that has a negative 'b' value, to see how many we have. Then, if we have more than 2 of them, we enter a block of code.

```
let arrayToFilter = [{
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: '',
}, {
    a: 0,
    b: -1,
    c: '',
}, {
    a: 0,
    b: -7,
    c: '',
}, {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: '',
}];

let filteredArray = arrayToFilter.filter(function(arrayItem){
    return arrayItem.b < 0;
});

if(filteredArray.length >=2){
    // do something
}
```

I hope that helps you understand this array operation!